# Timeout error when using long_running_recognize()

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am trying to transcribe a audio file using Google Speech API and was using long_running_recognize. It worked once but now I am starting to get the following error whenever i try - Any guidance is really appreciated.

Projects/Speech/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 127, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.GoogleAPICallError: None Unexpected state: Long-running operation had neither response nor error set.

Answer (score 0):

The error code is similar to this [Github discussion](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7024).

Verify your audio files if there are blank content to be translated (ex: entire audio is silent or audio only contains background noise)

A 3rd party tool such as [MP3 Splitter and Joiner](https://www.maniactools.com/soft/mp3-splitter-joiner/using_silence.shtml) allows you to detect portions of silence within your audio.